# Meshing of polygons

Tags: matlab, computational-geometry, mesh

I need to generate a sequence of increasingly denser high-quality triangular meshes for some pentagons in MATLAB.

I want to supply as my input

1. The coordinates of the 5 vertices of the pentagon
2. The desired (approximate) mesh-node spacing or the number of mesh-faces in the output mesh.

The output should be

1. A high-quality mesh
2. The list of points on the mesh-boundary (ie the boundary of the pentagon)

Are there any softwares to do this, preferably in MATLAB or elsewhere?

Comment: Triangular or quadrilateral meshes?

Comment: @ Bill Barth Triangular meshes. Made the edit

Answer (score 2):

http://geuz.org/gmsh/

This program is called gmsh it should be able to do exactly what your looking for. I recently posted an answer similar to this which can be found here (http://tinyurl.com/n6avzsz).

Once you have the program downloaded the way it works is by coding the .geo file. You can do this by hand, or code it into the .geo file. See this post for a sample of that (http://tinyurl.com/lme57dk).

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There is also Jonathan Shewchuck's *triangle* package that should be able to do the same for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the MATLAB [PDE Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/pde/?refresh=true) it has the necessary tools built in.